# JsonException No value error

Tags: android, json

I have got the following json.

```
    {
  "status": 1,
  "value": {
    "details": [
      {
        "shipment_no": "60178000059574",
        "shipment_ref_no": "VAPL/EXP/19",
        "proforma_invoice_no": "IN-70054000065076",
        "proforma_invoice_date": "06-FEB-16",
        "planned_shipment_date": "",
        "point_of_contact": {
          "empid": "60097000005728"
        },
        "products": {
          "0": "Coco Peat Low EC"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "0": "48 Pallets"
        },
        "rate": {ac
          "0": "215 MTS"
        },
        "amount": {
          "0": "617136"
        },
        "product_image": {
          "0": "http://localhost/bogi/export/ver-1/images/employee/Desert.jpg"
        },
        "status": "3"
      },
      {
        "shipment_no": "50108000007144",
        "shipment_ref_no": "VAPL/EXP/46/14-15",
        "proforma_invoice_no": "in-VAPL/EXP/46/14-15",
        "proforma_invoice_date": "03-FEB-16",
        "planned_shipment_date": "",
        "point_of_contact": {
          "empid": "60162000009888"
        },
        "products": {
          "0": "MAIZE/CORN STARCH"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "0": "38 PP Bags"
        },
        "rate": {
          "0": "429 MTS"
        },
        "amount": {
          "0": "1002409.98"
        },
        "product_image": {
          "0": "http://localhost/bogi/noimage.jpg"
        },
        "status": "5"
      },
      {
        "shipment_no": "60178000059574",
        "shipment_ref_no": "VAPL/EXP/120/15-16",
        "proforma_invoice_no": "in-123",
        "proforma_invoice_date": "02-FEB-16",
        "planned_shipment_date": "",
        "point_of_contact": {
          "empid": "60097000005728"
        },
        "products": {
          "0": "Coco Peat Low EC"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "0": "115 Pallets"
        },
        "rate": {
          "0": "267 MTS"
        },
        "amount": {
          "0": "2041882.5"
        },
        "product_image": {
          "0": "http://localhost/bogi/Desert.jpg"
        },
        "status": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
}


Following is my code to parse json.

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObjects = details.getJSONObject(i);
    String shipmentNo = jsonObjects.getString("shipment_no");
    JSONObject empId = jsonObject.getJSONObject("point_of_contact");
    JSONObject productId = jsonObject.getJSONObject("products");
    Iterator<String> iterator = empId.keys();
    Iterator<String> productIterator = productId.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        String key = iterator.next();
         Log.d(TAG,empId.optString(key));

        }

        while (productIterator.hasNext()){
        String key = iterator.next();
         Log.d(TAG,.optString(key));

        }
     }
```

I use volley to get the json response. The keys like `emp_id` and keys within `products` are dynamic. Hence I iterate through the json to get the keys along with values. But, it throws an error message saying `no value exists for pointOfContact` and `no value exists for products`.Why is that Im getting this error?

Comment: Did you try to print jsonObjects to see if it's clean ? And show us the first one please.

Comment: i have posted the unedited version of json.

Comment: i need escpecially the values within `products` whose key might increase or decrease numerically based on number of products